# How to update a numpy array based on a masked array w/ same dimension and shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays with same dimension and shape. this `nv_arr` array has null values (-9999). I've created a masked array `nv_mask` to mask all values besides -9999 to somehow "update" this `out` array by the position, without the need to create a new array.

In other words, numbers 0, 3, 6 and 2 must be replaced by -9999. How can I do that?

```
    >>> nv_arr
     ([[-9999,   123,   -9999],
       [-9999,   444,   444],
       [-9999,   323,   323]])

>>> nv_mask
[[-9999 -- -9999]
 [-9999 -- --]
 [-9999 -- --]]

 >>> out
      ([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `nv_mask` is a `MaskedArray`, you can call the `.mask` attribute to set values:

```
>>> out[~nv_mask.mask] = -9999
>>> out 
array([[-9999,     1, -9999],
       [-9999,     4,     5],
       [-9999,     7,     8]])
```

Comment: Almost correct ;-P `.mask` is True at the masked values, not the valid ones.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Ah, I see I botched up the initialisation of these arrays, so my answer needed a ~ it didn't have. Ty!